# How to create an Interactive 3D Graph in Python

Tags: python, graph, graphics, 3d, interactive

I am trying to create a 3D graph in python  where you can freely move the points on the graph in any of the 3 axis. while moving this points on the graph ,the point that were plotted are also updated. I tried using matplot but I couldn't freely move the points on the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/3d-charts/) for creating 3d graphs. They provide an interactive interface to play with chart along with different types of charts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`plotly-express`](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/)

```
# Python env: pip install plotly-express
# Anaconda env: conda install -c plotly plotly_express 

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly-express]

[image: plotly-express2]